# Consume data from local JSON file into website?

Tags: angularjs, json, excel, vuejs2

I work for a small publishing company with an internal website that displays a static HTML table of our published products.

We have a need to be able to list and sort published products (about 1-2 items are published per day) dynamically that is being fed from an Excel spreadsheet. The Excel spreadsheet is what we are currently using to maintain the data. The Excel spreadsheet is on a shared network drive available to the company.

I am familiar with AngularJS, ReactJS, and VueJS2 for front-end development and was w**ondering if I would be able to use one of those tools to consume a Excel file, parse it to JSON, and then display it dynamically on the client side.**

**Is something like this is possible?**

When a user finishes editing the Excel sheet and saves it to the shared network drive, is there a script that would automatically save the data as JSON? I assume we would then simply have our Javascript framework reference and consume the saved JSON to populate its published products list.

*Note: We are unable to use a relational database at this time (ie MySQL).*

Comment: I would think this would be easier to do if the outputted as csv, but not impossible with an xls file. Check out [this article](http://www.anthonydebarros.com/2013/02/05/get-json-from-excel-using-python-xlrd/) that shows how to do this with python.

Comment: Do you mean you want to have a static HTML page that can open an excel file, edit it, and save the results?

Comment: @BertEvans, no. I simply want to display data on a webpage that is consuming a local file to populate data.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 - generating json from excel...

front-end technologies are not the way to go. You need to run a service that watches folder for change (like nodejs or python). Saving as csv instead of xls might make things easier as you may not need extra libraries to make sense of your xls file

Part 2, displaying json data...

Your browser, by default, cannot load a local json file. So you may need to run a server (again nodejs and python make this relatively easy) to host your json file.

there are many ways of presenting data these days, but without knowing some of your particular and based on the information you did share, looks like you've got a steep learning curve to get something like this going.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. I am really open to any ideas as long as I don't need to query a remote database. It has to be a local file. I will research nodejs as I am a little familiar with that technology.

Comment: it doesn't seem like you'd need a database at all. If you want to update a user that there has been a change, you may want to look into web sockets as-well (https://socket.io/)